# How to set the django-channels ChannelsLiveServerTestCase server port?

Tags: django-channels

I am trying to write tests with selenium and I am using ChannelsLiveServerTestCase.
I need to set the port the server listens to.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should be a rare situation where someone needs to set the port as no one answered the question.
Anyway, I had to dig into the source code of daphne.
In testing.py file look for the line

`endpoints = build_endpoint_description_strings(host=self.host, port=0)`

in my case it was line 139 and change it into

`endpoints = build_endpoint_description_strings(host=self.host, port=WHICHEVER_PORT_YOU_WANT)`